# conjugacy classes and order of group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, permutations

Suppost that $k_G(A)$ denotes the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ that intersects $A$ non-trivially ($A$ is an arbitrary subset of $G$) and $M=G^{'}Z(G)$. Also suppose that $G$ is non-solvable, $\frac{G}{M}$ is cyclic group of order 6  and $k_G(G-M)=5$. What can we say about $G$?

Comment: Is $k_G$ the same as $K_G$? Also $G-M$ is not a subgroup of $G$ so did you mean that $A$ is an arbitrary *subset* of $G$?

Comment: @Derek Holt: yes I mean $k_G$ and A is an arbitrary subset of G.

Comment: I have just noticed that you are assuming that $G$ is non-solvable. Since, form the answer below, we know that $M$ is abelian, there are no non-solvable examples,

Answer (score 1):

So all elements in each of the $5$ nontrivial cosets of $M$ in $G$ are conjugate. hence they all have centralizers of order $6$. So if $g \in G$ such that $gM$ generates $G/M$, then $g$ must have order $6$, and $G$ is a Frobenius group with kernel $M$ and complement $\langle g \rangle$.

Comment: Since $G$ is a Frobenius group with a complement of even order, it implies that $M$ is abelian. Now is it possible to determine these Frobenius groups? Another question: with the above notations if $\frac{G}{M}$ is cyclic group of order 6, where $M=G^{'}Z(G)$, then what can we say about $k_G(G-N)$?

Comment: So $M$ is an abelian group of odd order admitting a fixed point free automorphism of order $3$. Yes, it is possible to determine such groups $M$. You can say obviously say that $k_G(G - M) \ge 5$ and it can be arbitrarily large. I have no idea what sort of thing you would like to say about it

Comment: Do you know any references that classify abelian groups of odd order admitting a fixed point free automorphism of order 3? If in the second question $G$ has the property that "$G$ has at least $p-1$ non-central classes whose order of representative is a multiple of $p$",($p$ is a prime dividing order of $G$), then what can we say about $k_G(G-M)$? Is there an upper bound for it?

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea about an upper bound for $k_G(G-M)$ with the property that "$G$ has at least $p−1$ non-central classes whose order of representative is a multiple of $p$",($p$ is a prime dividing order of $G$), where $\frac{G}{M}$ is the cyclic group of order 6? Can we say that $k_G(G-M)\leq 4$?

Comment: Your original question has been answered, so you should not keep asking new questions as comments. As I said before, if $M$ is any normal of $G$ and $G/M$ is cyclic of order six then clearly $k_G(G-M) \ge 5$. In general $k_G(G-M) \ge k_{G/M}(G/M)-1$.